# Need suggestions for AJAX based Java web application with REST capabilities

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest

We are developing a widget based web application in Java (UI looks like http://pageflakes.com). We ping about 20 APIs, analyze and present some statistics (one API result per widget, so 20 widgets in total). We want to use jQuery for AJAX communication for the widgets. Since our previous projects use JSF, we started off with it, but observed that AJAX communication for widget based approach doesn't go well with JSF. We are thinking of going with REST based design, so that we can re-use the services created for each widget for mobile based scenarios in future. Can you suggest a good architecture stack for this?

Comment: yeah, but though JSF 2 has AJAX features built in, we are also looking in terms of exposing data as services, so that they can be reused. Also, we use JavaScript based visualization graphs. So thought that having custom AJAX libraries is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think [wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) is a good choice. You can find an example of how to create restful urls [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/wicket-creating-restful-urls). I can't say anything about JSF as I always kept myself away from it (for some reason I've never liked it).

Stay away from Tapestry 5, unless you have suicidal tendencies.

I would also suggest you to use JRuby or Clojure, but I think it might be a long shot.